# Elliptic curves of high rank over quadratic extensions

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Are there examples of elliptic curves which has rank 0 over $\mathbb{Q}$, but acquires a high rank ( $\geq 2$) over some quadratic extension?

More generally, are there known bounds for a given extension of degree $n$, how big can the rank be if you start with a rank 0 curve ( over $\mathbb{Q}$ )?

Comment: The first question is easy. Take a curve $A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with rank as large as it can get. There exists (plenty of) quadratic twists $E$ of rank $0$.

Comment: Based on the previous comment, we should be able to **quickly** show that the jump in rank could be at least $20$ starting with Elkies - Klagsbrun (2020) Z/2Z curve of rank $20$ posted on [Andrej Dujella's page](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/tors/z2.html). I'll post the Magma code when I find the suitable quadratic extension.

Answer (score 4):

I think you will find this paper helpful:

- Robert J. Lemke Oliver, Frank Thorne, *Rank growth of elliptic curves in nonabelian extensions*, International Mathematics Research Notices, Volume 2021, Issue 24 (2021) pp 18411–18441, doi:[10.1093/imrn/rnz307](https://doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnz307), arXiv:[1810.04018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04018).

Answer (score 4):

Following the comments, we start with the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ curve
$$
E=[ 0, 0, 0, -15650411093524454493683423178813553233328484724599030637228,
492395613211229713687666165349208268497505680211462943972719303000171030884176146690352 ]
$$
of rank $0$ and extend it over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ to obtain the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ [curve found by Elkies - Klagsbrun (2020)](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/z2.html) of rank $20$.

The use of Magma's `TwoPowerIsogenyDescentRankBound` significantly speeds up the process.

```
SetClassGroupBounds("GRH");
E := EllipticCurve([ 0, 0, 0, -15650411093524454493683423178813553233328484724599030637228, 492395613211229713687666165349208268497505680211462943972719303000171030884176146690352 ]);
Coefficients(E);
TwoPowerIsogenyDescentRankBound(E);
QT := MinimalModel(QuadraticTwist(E, 2));
Coefficients(QT);
QT eq EllipticCurve([1,-1,1,-244537673336319601463803487168961769270757573821859853707,961710182053183034546222979258806817743270682028964434238957830989898438151121499931]);

[ 0, 0, 0, -15650411093524454493683423178813553233328484724599030637228,
4923956132112297136876661653492082684975056802114629439727193030001710308841761\
46690352 ]
0 [ 11, 5, 2, 2, 1 ]
[ 7, 5, 2, 2, 1 ]
[ 1, -1, 1, -244537673336319601463803487168961769270757573821859853707,
9617101820531830345462229792588068177432706820289644342389578309898984381511214\
99931 ]
true
```

A great collection of references on the topic is provided on Andrej Dujella's page [High rank elliptic curves with prescribed torsion over quadratic fields](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/torsquad.html). Some of the papers also discuss the extensions over cubic and/or quartic number fields, e.g.

- J. Bosman, P. Bruin, A. Dujella and F. Najman, *Ranks of elliptic curves with prescribed torsion over number fields*, Int. Math. Res. Not. 2014 (11) (2014), 2885-2923, doi:[10.1093/imrn/rnt013](https://doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnt013), arXiv:[1201.0252](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0252), [PDF](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/pdf/ranknf.pdf).
- D. Jeon, C. H. Kim, and Y. Lee, *Families of elliptic curves over cubic number fields with prescribed torsion subgroups*, Mathematics of Computation, Volume 80, Number 273, January 2011, pp. 579–591, doi:[10.1090/S0025-5718-10-02369-0](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-10-02369-0).